# Google app engine (php): How to handle html forms

Tags: php, html, forms

Can anyone help me with html forms in php on google app engine. I have two files, first file sends username and password to second file, and that second file should display appropriate message.

This is first.html

```
<html>
<body>

    <form action="hello.php" method="POST">
        <b>Username: </b> <input type="text" name="username"> <br>
        <b>Password: </b> <input type="text" name="password"> <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is hello.php (second file):

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($password == 'user' and $password =='pass')
echo 'Success';
else
echo 'Fail';

?>
```

When I press Submit button in first.html my two textboxes just goes blank and my link changes, but I don't see any message.If I run hello.php manually then it shows message.

Comment: What this means: `my two textboxes just goes blank and my link changes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to app.yaml, before your main URI handler

```
- url: /hello.php*
  script: hello.php
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention I solved this. I have done something similar what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird. `$password` cant hold both values ta the same time

```
if($password == 'user' and $password =='pass')
```

should probably be

```
 if($username == 'user' && $password =='pass')
```

Answer (score 0):

change the content of Hello.php file with this

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($username == 'user' && $password =='pass')
{
   echo 'Success';
}
else
{
   echo 'Fail';
}
```

Comment: I still get same results, it seems everything works, just hello.php doesn't show up

Comment: Maybe google app engine doesn't allow this, I know this works on regular php server

Comment: now try the code have made little changes, now it should be working

Comment: It's the same, there must be something wrong with google app engine, since this works for my apache server

Comment: Finally i got that PHP on Google is not good for complex PHP code, due to THE big changes Google made to normal usage. I have problems too using forms. It's a little weird.